# Is there a way to convert this box shadow into a drop shadow?

Tags: css

Is there a way to convert this box shadow into a drop shadow?

```
box-shadow: inset 0 0 0.32vw 0.2vw #0a0e0f40;
```

I'd like to achieve something like this, but with drop-shadow:

```css
.card {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 2vw;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
 box-shadow: inset 0 0 2vw 0.4vw #0a0e0f40;
 
}

body {
  background: #e2e1e0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="card card-1"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

drop-shadow() does not have an inset and spread-radius, so no.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/drop-shadow()

Unless you mean just removing the inset property...

```css
#yoda {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  
  margin: 3px;
  
  background: darkgreen;

  box-shadow: 0 0 0.32vw 0.2vw #0a0e0f40;
}

#spongebob {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  
  margin: 3px;
  
  background: yellow;

  box-shadow: 0.4vw 0.4vw 0.32vw 0.2vw #0a0e0f40;
}
```

```html
<div id="yoda"></div>

<div id="spongebob"></div>
```

Comment: Hi @nora, I edited my question with an example of how it should look. But it seems that it's not possible with drop shadow..